# Publish release upon successful pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using a private `gitlab-runner` to build an ISO and then upload the ISO and its log to my S3 bucket. This section of the pipeline works without a hitch, but I recently decided to create "release" upon a successful pipeline. For this reason, I am using the following `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
stages:
  - build
  - release

build_amd64:
  stage: build

  # Do not run the pipeline if the following files/directories are modified:
  # except:
  #   changes:
  #     - Pictures/
  #     - .gitignore
  #     - FUNDING.yml
  #     - LICENSE
  #     - README.md

  tags:
    - digitalocean

  timeout: 4 hours

  before_script:
    # Make sure the dependencies for the build are up-to-date:
    - /usr/bin/apt update
    - /usr/bin/apt install --only-upgrade -y curl git live-build cdebootstrap

    # Save Job ID
    - echo 'Saving $CI_JOB_ID to .env'
    - echo BUILD_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID >> .env

  script:
    # Build the ISO:
    - ./build.sh --arch amd64 --variant i3_gaps --verbose

  after_script:
    - |
      if [ $CI_JOB_STATUS == 'success' ]; then
        # Remove everything except the "images" folder:
        shopt -s extglob 
        /usr/bin/rm -rf !(images/)

        # Upload log:
        # /usr/bin/s3cmd put ./images/log s3://$S3_BUCKET/download/log
        
        # Set log access to public:
        # /usr/bin/s3cmd setacl s3://$S3_BUCKET/download/log --acl-public

        # Upload iso:
        # /usr/bin/s3cmd put ./images/iso s3://$S3_BUCKET/download/iso
        
        # Set iso access to public:
        # /usr/bin/s3cmd setacl s3://$S3_BUCKET/download/iso --acl-public

      else
        # If pipeline fails, skip the upload process:
        echo 'Skipping upload process due to job failure'

        sleep 5; /usr/sbin/reboot
        /usr/bin/screen -dm /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/sleep 5; /usr/sbin/reboot;'

      fi

  artifacts:
    reports:
      # Ensure that we have access to .env in the next stage
      dotenv: .env

publish_release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest

  stage: release
  
  needs:
    - job: build_amd64
      artifacts: true
 
  release:
    name: 'ISO | $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA | $BUILD_JOB_ID'

    description: "Created and released via Gitlab CI/CD."
    
    tag_name: "$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"

    ref: '$CI_COMMIT_SHA'
    
    assets:
      links:
        - name: "ISO"
          url: "https://foo.bar"
          link_type: "image"
        
        - name: "Build Log"
          URL: "https://foo.bar"
          link_type: "other"
```

However I have realized that when  the `release` job runs, it creates the release without any issues, but then creates a new pipeline with the new tag (in this case`$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA`), instead of initially creating this new pipeline with this tag, instead of `main` branch.

I checked the documentation but I cannot find anything regarding this matter.

Is there a way to not run a pipeline when a release is published?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that because the specified tag doesn't exist, it will be created with the release. This causes a tagged pipeline to run (just as if you created the tag and pushed it).

If you just want to ignore tag pipelines, you can use a workflow rule to exclude them:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never  # ignore pipelines for tags
    - when: always # run the pipeline otherwise
```

Comment: I added this to the top of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` (https://pastebin.com/7mwTG7Yg) but this is throwing `This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: jobs:publish_release config contains unknown keys: image, release.` error for some reason, despite the syntax and usage looking correct from what I can tell (when I compare it to the Gitlab docs)

Comment: @Arszilla no idea why you'd get that issue. Doesn't make sense to me that your `publish_release` job would suddenly throw a validation issue by adding another section that is unrelated. Probably an accidental typo or something... Maybe check the git diff between now and when it worked?

Comment: Resolved the issue after practically re-writing the `.gitlab-ci.yml`. Not sure what the cause was as it all looked normal, and no issues with indentations. Thanks a bunch!